# Why Do I Keep Getting Errors About Else Statements?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement

Let the function f be defined by the rule that for n ≥ 0, f(n) = n if n < 3 and f(n) = f(n − 1) + 2f(n − 2)
if n ≥ 3. Use a for loop to implement f in R

Here is my loop and errors

```r
for (i in 0:10) {
  if (i < 3)
    print(i)
  } else if (i >= 3) {
Error: unexpected 'else' in:
"    print(i)
  } else"
>     print((i-1)+2(i-2))
Error in print((i - 1) + 2(i - 2)) : attempt to apply non-function
>   }
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

This has been a recurring theme on the else statements. Why are they not working?

Comment: You seem to be missing the opening `{` after the first `if`. Make sure that all `}` have a matching `{` before it.

Comment: Also you need to do `2*(i-2)`

Answer (score 2):

This question should likely be closed as "typo", but here is something visual to look for when working on code: most code editors support "paren-matching", which is usually extended to include brackets and braces. Most editors also support keyboard shortcuts to navigate to the matching paren/brace/bracket.

**Rstudio**: if I place my cursor immediately to the right of the close(right)-brace, (RStudio is only highlighting the matching brace), you'll see the matching brace highlighted. Use [`Ctrl-P`](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts) to move to the matching brace.

[image: RStudio brace matching]

If you're a **Notepad++** user, then it shows both (in red, in this theme). Use [`Ctrl-B`](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15610/finding-matching-brackets/2) to move to the matching brace.

[image: notepad plus plus brace matching]

Lastly, if you by chance use **Emacs/ESS**, it also highlights both. The default emacs shortcuts are [`C-M-p` (back) and `C-M-n` (forward)](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NavigatingParentheses).

[image: emacs brace matching]

In short, in this case one might notice that the matching opening brace is on a `for` line, not the `if` line, and correct accordingly.

The correct code, including @akash87's fix, is

```r
for (i in 0:10) {
  if (i < 3) {
    print(i)
  } else if (i >= 3) {
    print((i-1)+2*(i-2))
  }
}
```

or, slightly reduced:

```r
for (i in 0:10) {
  if (i < 3) {
    print(i)
  } else {
    print((i-1)+2(i-2))
  }
}
```

Comment: Whoa! All of this has been helpful! Thank you so much, everyone!